# Angular auth guard without using localstorage or cookies

Tags: angular

I have an angular project whose login is controlled by interceptor. The auth and session maintenance of browser with server is written over here. I want to introduce login as auth guard and move the redirect logic to guard service.

The reason why I wanted to do it is: Whenever I am opening any page for the first time in the browser, that page UI is visible for some half a second and then redirecting to login page. Actually I don't want to show that page even for half a second without authentication. So I planned to introduce auth as guard to all the modules.

I looked at the answers on internet and found some using some variable storage which is shared across login, logout and auth guard and the auth guard is checking for that variable and based on it's value either it is redirecting. I don't want to use any extra variable. I am looking for any option to communicate with browser session, because browser already maintaining it.

My interceptor looks like:

```
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const xhr = request.clone({
            headers: request.headers.set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
        });
        //return next.handle(xhr);
        return next.handle(xhr).pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                // do stuff with response if you want
            }
        }, (err: any) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('login');
                }
            }
        }));
    }

}
```

I am doing a get call on home page and the default routing is referring to that page.

Any pointer will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Guard is the thing that can cancel navigation so that page won't be displayed. So basically yes, a guard is the place where you can check authentication and prevent navigation if user is not authenticated. The way you can check if user authenticated or not depends on authentication type.

For example, if you use cookie authentication, a good practice is to have an endpoint returning current user data. So authGuard can make a call to this endpoint and then check its result to cancel navigation if user is not authenticated.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient, private _router: Router) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
      return this._httpClient.get('<current user info endpoint>', {withCredentials:true}) // makes a call with a cookie
        .pipe(
           map(response => response.status !== 401)
        )
        .toPromise()
        .then(canActivate => {
          if(!canActivate) {
            this._router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Note that it's not good to make an API call for every navigation. It's better to cache authentication data. For example, you can have a state in a service or in the localStorage.

Comment: This doesn't solve a problem with SSR and AuthGuard reaching cached token in localStorage, because server cant reach localStorage, its not a browser.